# explicit `attr_writer` for Rails models in order to add YARD doc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, model, attributes, rubymine

say i have a Rails model created as:

```
rails generate model SuperModel name:string
```

it then creates a migration for a new table:

```
create_table 'super_models' |t|
    t.string  'name'
    ...
end
```

and a model class:

```
class SuperModel < ActiveRecord::Base ...
```

i know that rails generates a few methods for the name attribute similar to what i can manually do:

```
class SuperModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    # YARD doc
    # @attr [String] ...
    attr_writer :name
end
```

which can then be picked up for project documentation by doc-tools and auto-completion, and in-place documentation lookup with IntelliJ (+RubyMine, etc)

this might be XY problem, but if i do add the `attr_writer` attributes manually, how does this affect how `ActiveRecord` et al work with for generated methods like  `super_model.changed?`.  what i want is compiled language facilities like type-checking/auto-complete and docs in the IDE.

Comment: You can add the Yard `@attr` tags without explicitly adding a getter/setter.  It was a while since I used Rubymine but I do believe it actually reads the schema and picks up attributes.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader`, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` are meta-programming utility methods that add setters and getters. Thus using them on a model can clobber the ActiveModel setters which can mess up things like taint checking and `ActiveModel::Dirty`.